# Desktop lockscreens when I press suspend

Tags: suspend, 22.04, shutdown, startup

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) dual-booting with Windows 11. Not long ago, when I launched the Software Updater, it told me some error that I don't remember the phrasing of, but ending with suggesting a partial update. I went through with it and restarted my system. The software updater now says:

> The software on this computer is up to date.

However, when I press *Suspend*, my PC goes to lock screen and when I press *Power Off* it takes a considerable amount of time to tun off.
Then it doesn't turn on unless I press the physical restart button after the power button.

What is the issue and how can I solve this?

My system's specs:

- Motherboard: MS-7D18 B560M PRO VDH WIFI
- CPU: 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-11600K @ 3.90GHz × 12
- RAM: 2 x f4-3000C16S-16GISB
- Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti (lite hash rate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that the nouveau graphics driver doesn't support suspend on the GeForce RTX 3060 series yet